# Setup and Deployment: How to change installation folder names, icons and shortcuts

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, icons, setup-deployment

There are about 10 tasks regarding assembly (program) names and icons required to ensure that a Visual Studio Setup and Deployment project works successfully.  Thus far, this information seems to be strewn about online, so my question is: Is there a single list describing all of these tasks?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a summary of how to change/modify icons, program and folder names, and shortcuts of an assembly that's installed in Windows.

After you have added a Setup and Deployment Project to your VS Solution, everything you want to change regarding icons and program or folder names is controlled from the Properties menu of the Setup Project.

**Changing the name of the .msi installation file that you distribute:**

To change this filename.msi, right-click on the Setup Project, select Properties, and you will see a textbox with the filename of the .msi file. Change it, save, and you are done. By the way, there is a setup.exe executable also created during deployment, but Microsoft and most groups recommend distributing the .msi file.

**Changing the program's Icon which appears in Installed Programs of the Control Panel**

Left-click on the Setup Project in the VS Solution.  You will then see all the Properties.  The first entry called "AddRemoveProgramIcon" is the icon that appears in the list of installed programs in Control Panel.

**How to install your assembly to appear in C:\Program Files (x86) or C:\Program Files**

To install your program as a 32-bit assembly in C:\Program Files (x86), select the "x86" option in the "TargetPlatform" property of the Setup Project.

To install your program as a 64-bit assembly in C:\Program Files, select the "x64" option in the "TargetPlatform" property of the Setup Project.

I always select "x64" for the TargetPlatform property, and then on the VS menu go to Project-->"programname" Properties-->Compile-->Target CPU and select "Any CPU".  This will allow 32-bit Windows users to have the program installed in their C:\Program Files (x86) folder.

**How to change the company name folder where your assembly is installed in either  C:\Program Files (x86) or C:\Program Files**

The company name folder is the text string that you enter in the "Manufacturer" property of the Setup Project.

**How to change the product name folder in the company name folder where your assembly is installed**

The product name folder is based on the text string you enter in the "ProductName" property of the Setup Project.

**How to change the product name listed in installed programs in Control Panel**

The product name listed in the installed programs is based on the text string you enter in the "ProductName" property of the Setup Project.

**How to setup desktop program names and icons which appear on the program's icon on user's desktop**

To begin, left-click on the Setup Project, then select from the icons in the solution bar above the "File System Editor" icon.  You will now see three folders:

- Application folder
- User's Desktop
- User's Program Menu

**Application Folder.**   Double-click on the Application folder.  You will then notice a Primary output entry.  Right-click on Primary output and create **two** shortcuts to the primary output.   Cut & paste each of the shortcuts into the User's Desktop and User's Program Menu folders.  Next, rename the shortcuts within these two folders - **THIS PROGRAM NAME WILL BE NAME UNDER THE ICON ON THE USER'S DESKTOP, AND PROGRAM MENU LIST.**

Also, right click the Application folder and add (File) the icon file you want to show on the user's desktop.

**User's Desktop.**  Right-click on the desktop shortcut you renamed in this folder.  The Properties tab will appear.  To specify the icon that will appear on the user's desktop, select Icon on the properties tab, then browse to the Application folder and double-click on the icon file.  Click on Apply.

**User's Program Menu.**  Right-click on the desktop shortcut you renamed in this folder.  The Properties tab will appear.  To specify the icon that will appear in the program menu, select Icon on the properties tab, then browse to the Application folder and double-click on the icon file.   Click on Apply.

Comment: Can you delete your shortcuts afterwards?